# Selectively Update SQL Server Database Schema from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, schema-compare

I'm using the schema compare tool inside of VS 2010 to compare my Dev and Prod SQL Servers.  There's a bunch of changes to the Dev that I don't want pushed to the Prod server, but there are a few that I do want pushed.  Is there a way I can select the ones I do want (right-click or something) and fire those off to the Prod server one by one?  I know I can select "skip-all" and then go un-skip the ones I want.  Just looking for something more efficient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's shockingly simple: "Export To Editor" and then manually comment out the pieces of the script you don't need. The Ctrl+K+C keyboard shortcut makes that a pleasantly speedy process.